# What does this perl regex to read server JSON reply do?

Tags: json, perl

I am reading some code that parses the json return from a web site, a Dynamic DNS provider if it matters.

```perl
 $reply =~ qr/{(?:[^{}]*|(?R))*}/mp;
```

What will this match?

I am reading this https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut to try and understand.
So far I understand the following

It will match something that starts with '{' and ends with '}'.

`(?:` means not to extract the regexp. I assume this is for speed?

Then it will match something that is not '{' or '}' as many times (e.g. fjksfksdh) which is not necessarily proper JSON syntax as far as I can tell.

Then I have no idea what is the meaning of `?R` and I struggle putting it all together in the end.

Can someone help me out?

Sorry perl and JSON noob here.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to try to get data out of JSON. Use a JSON parser - perl has several available (I like [`JSON::MaybeXS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS), but worst case use [`JSON::PP`](https://perldoc.perl.org/JSON::PP) that's part of the core perl modules)

Comment: `$var =~ qr/.../` is... odd but apparently legal. You'd normally use `$var =~ m/.../` to do a regular expression match, and `qr//` to compile one for later use. Looks like the RE itself is meant to match nested balanced curly braces (The `(?R)` is a recursive match) with other stuff inside.

Comment: It tries to check for a complete JSON document by looking for properly nested braces. Of course, it can fail spectacularly if any string contains `{` or `}`.

Comment: `(?:... )` is like parens in mathematics. It's defining the operands of `|`, and it's defining to what the `*` applies.

Comment: Tip: The `m` modifier is useless. It modifies `^` and `$`, neither of which are used. (No, `[^...]` is not `^`.)

Comment: Tip: The use of `qr/.../` is weird. It's treated as `m/.../` here, which is usually written as `/.../`.

Comment: @Shawn, Re "*apparently legal*", If you provide something other than `m//`, `s///` or `tr//`, it's treated an expression that provides a regex pattern to match against. For example, also legal: `$_ =~ "a"` (Same as `$_ =~ /a/`)

Comment: As told already, apparently this just checks whether there is a match -- so whether the JSON is valid?  The critical and a tricky to follow part is the recursion, `(?R)`.  Imagine that you actually capture, `([^{}]*)`, and let's simplify the regex to: `/{ (?:([^{}]*) | (?R)) }/x` Then if your `$reply` string is `{one {two {last} end}}` the capture (`$1`) will be `last`. So it'll drill down the balanced nested `{}`.   However, this can get messed up with different input in various ways.

Comment: [contd] To check for JSON, parse the JSON with a library, and put that inside `eval{}`, which catches exceptions thrown by the library when parsing fails. Then check `$@`. Simple.

Comment: Btw, from what I see the given regex matches unbalanced braces as well.  For example, remove/add curlies in `{beg {mid} end}` and it still matches.  Add more deeply (improperly) nested braces, not necessarily paired, and it's the same, it matches.  (Maybe I'm missing a point of some sort here?)  So it seems bad even just for that...

Comment: Do you have control over this code -- can you change it?  Then an answer would make sense.  If so, how is this `$reply =~ ...` expression used, can you show its complete statement?

Comment: Thanks for your replies all. The code is found here github.com/ddclient/ddclient/blob/develop/ddclient.in#L6057 and the comment says that it will strip the header. Another way it is done in the same file is in https://github.com/ddclient/ddclient/blob/36b8db950f85311c583cbedb5f411a99b47fe3e4/ddclient.in#L6140. It looks like after the result of the regex it is fed into JSON::PP decode_json.

Comment: "_The code is found here..._"  -- this helps: that line merely matches, and then the next line uses the match -- to parse the (expected) JSON by a library, in an `eval` (as in my comment above).

Comment: The regex by itself can be translated as this:
`?:`     Non capturing group. Groups tokens without creating a capture group.

`[^{}]*` Matches anything but this `{` and this `}`, zero or more times(`*`).

`|`      Alternation. Works as an OR betwwen the patterns before and after this.

`(?R)` matches the entire pattern

`*` matches all the previous zero or unlimited times.